# Customizing the variation selector for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce

The variations are displayed as numbers in this code, such as 'x feature, y feature, z feature' listed one after the other. How can I modify this to display them as the original variation selector?

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="sidebar_wrapper">
        
    <div class="sidebar_top"></div>
    
    <div class="sidebar">
     
        <div class="content">
            
            <?php
                //Get tour price
                $tour_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_price', true);
                
                if(!empty($tour_price))
                {
                    $tour_discount_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_discount_price', true);
            ?>
            <div class="single_tour_header_price">
                <div class="single_tour_price">
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($tour_discount_price))
                    {
                    ?>
                        <span class="normal_price">
                            <?php echo esc_html(grandtour_format_tour_price($tour_price)); ?>
                        </span>
                        <?php echo esc_html(grandtour_format_tour_price($tour_discount_price)); ?>
                    <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    ?>
                        <?php echo esc_html(grandtour_format_tour_price($tour_price)); ?>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="single_tour_per_person">
                    <?php esc_html_e('Per Person', 'grandtour' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
    
            <?php
                //Get tour booking method
                $tour_booking_method = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_booking_method', true);
            ?>
            <div class="single_tour_booking_wrapper themeborder <?php echo esc_attr($tour_booking_method); ?>">
                <?php
                        //Check how to display booking form
                        switch($tour_booking_method)
                        {
                        case 'contact_form7':
                        default:
                            $tour_booking_contactform7 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_booking_contactform7', true);
                            echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="'.esc_attr($tour_booking_contactform7).'"]');
                        break;
                        
                        case 'woocommerce_product':
                            $tour_booking_product = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_booking_product', true);
                ?>
                        <div class="single_tour_booking_woocommerce_wrapper">
                            <?php
                                if(class_exists('Woocommerce'))
                                {
                                    $obj_product = wc_get_product($tour_booking_product);
                                    
                                    if($obj_product->is_type('simple')) 
                                    {
                            ?>
                            <?php esc_html_e("Click button below to book this tour and make a payment.", 'grandtour'); ?>
                            <button data-product="<?php echo esc_attr($tour_booking_product); ?>" data-processing="<?php esc_html_e("Please wait...", 'grandtour'); ?>" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php').esc_attr("?action=grandtour_add_to_cart&product_id=".$tour_booking_product); ?>" class="single_tour_add_to_cart button"><?php esc_html_e("Book This Tour", 'grandtour'); ?></button>
                            <?php
                                    } //end simple product
                                    else if($obj_product->is_type('variable')) 
                                    {
                            ?>
                            <form id="tour_variable_form">
                            <?php
                                        //Get all product variation
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
                                            'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
                                            'numberposts'   => -1,
                                            'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
                                            'order'         => 'ASC',
                                            'post_parent'   => $tour_booking_product
                                        );
                                        $variations = get_posts( $args ); 
                                         
                                        foreach ($variations as $variation)
                                        {
                                            
                                            //Get variation ID
                                            $variation_ID = $variation->ID;
                                         
                                            //Get variations meta
                                            $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_ID);
                                         
                                            //Get variation title & price
                                            $variation_price = $product_variation->get_price();
                                            $variation_price_html = $product_variation->get_price_html();
                                            
                                            $variation_title = wc_get_formatted_variation($product_variation->get_variation_attributes(), true, false);
                                ?>
                                
                                <div class="tour_product_variable_wrapper">
                                    <div class="tour_product_variable_title">
                                        <?php echo esc_html($variation_title); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tour_product_variable_qty">
                                        <input type="number" name="<?php echo esc_attr($variation_ID); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr($variation_ID); ?>" value="0" min="0"/>
                                    </div>
                                    &nbsp;x&nbsp;
                                    <div id="tour_product_variable_price_<?php echo esc_attr($variation_ID); ?>" class="tour_product_variable_price" data-price="<?php echo esc_attr($variation_price); ?>">
                                        <?php echo $variation_price_html; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <?php
                                        }
                                ?>
                            </form>
                                
                            <button data-product="<?php echo esc_attr($tour_booking_product); ?>" data-processing="<?php esc_html_e("Please wait...", 'grandtour'); ?>" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php').esc_attr("?action=grandtour_add_to_cart&product_id=".$tour_booking_product); ?>" class="single_tour_add_to_cart product_variable button"><?php esc_html_e("Book This Tour", 'grandtour'); ?></button>
                                
                                <?php       
                                    } //end variable product
                                    else
                                    {
                            ?>
                            <?php esc_html_e("Click button below to book this tour and make a payment.", 'grandtour'); ?>
                            <button data-product="<?php echo esc_attr($tour_booking_product); ?>" data-processing="<?php esc_html_e("Please wait...", 'grandtour'); ?>" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php').esc_attr("?action=grandtour_add_to_cart&product_id=".$tour_booking_product); ?>" class="single_tour_add_to_cart button"><?php esc_html_e("Book This Tour", 'grandtour'); ?></button>
                            <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                <?php
                        break;
                        
                        case 'external':
                            $tour_booking_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_booking_url', true);
                ?>
                        <div class="single_tour_booking_external_wrapper">
                            <?php esc_html_e("Click button below to begin booking", 'grandtour'); ?>&nbsp;<?php the_title(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($tour_booking_url); ?>" class="button" target="_blank"><?php esc_html_e("Book This Tour", 'grandtour'); ?></a>
                        </div>
                <?php
                        break;
                        
                        case 'html':
                            $tour_booking_html = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tour_booking_html', true);
                ?>
                        <div class="single_tour_html_wrapper">
                            <?php echo grandtour_apply_content($tour_booking_html); ?>
                        </div>
                <?php
                        break;
                        }
                        
                        $tour_view_count = grandtour_get_post_view($post->ID, true);
                        if($tour_view_count > 0)
                        {
                ?>
                <div class="single_tour_view_wrapper themeborder">
                    <div class="single_tour_view_desc">
                        <?php esc_html_e("This tour's been viewed", 'grandtour'); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo number_format($tour_view_count); ?>&nbsp;<?php esc_html_e("times in the past week", 'grandtour'); ?>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="single_tour_view_icon ti-alarm-clock"></div>
                </div>
                <br class="clear"/>
                <?php
                        }
                    ?>
            </div>
            
            <?php
                //Check if enable tour sharing
                $tg_tour_single_share = kirki_get_option('tg_tour_single_share');
                
                if(!empty($tg_tour_single_share))
                {
            ?>
            <a id="single_tour_share_button" href="javascript:;" class="button ghost themeborder"><span class="ti-email"></span><?php esc_html_e("Share this tour", 'grandtour'); ?></a>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            
            <?php 
                if (is_active_sidebar('single-tour-sidebar')) { ?>
                    <ul class="sidebar_widget">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('single-tour-sidebar'); ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php } ?>
            
            <?php 
                if (function_exists('users_online') && !isset($_COOKIE['grandtour_users_online'])): ?>
               <div class="single_tour_users_online_wrapper themeborder">
                   <div class="single_tour_users_online_icon">
                        <span class="ti-info-alt"></span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="single_tour_users_online_content">
                        <?php users_online(); ?>
                   </div>
               </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <br class="clear"/>
    
    <div class="sidebar_bottom"></div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to customize the variation selector.

Comment: I changed the selector to a select box, but it's not performing the add to cart function at the moment.